# Alternatives to stamp based brush stroke rendering?

Tags: graphics, webgl, drawing, curve, spline

I'm making my own drawing application with typescript + webgl and I'm running into a little trouble...

Initially I opted for 'stamp based' rendering of brush strokes which just takes a brush texture and densely renders it along a path that the user draws. My only issue with this method is its ability to hander strokes with varying opacity. The stamps are so densely packed that their alpha values will blend with each other, resulting in a fully opaque stroke

The next best thing looks to be 'skeletal' based brush rendering which you can see a visualization of on page 97 of this book

https://www.google.com/books/edition/Non_Photorealistic_Computer_Graphics/Kq_dU65kngUC?q=&gbpv=1#f=false

This also almost works, but I'm having problems with getting textures to overlap to create the illusion of a continuous curve. Putting circles on each quad, for example, would give white space between successive quads. Any simple methods of fixing this I haven't come across in my research

For anybody experienced with this kind of stuff, is stamp based rendering the way? Or are there more complicated and better ways of doing this?

Some of the papers I've looked at but don't fit what I'm looking for:

https://diglib.eg.org/bitstream/handle/10.2312/egsh.20101055.089-092/089-092.pdf?sequence=1
https://diglib.eg.org/bitstream/handle/10.2312/egsh.20101055.089-092/089-092.pdf?sequence=1
https://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/painting-with-texture/media/Painting_with_Texture_electronic.pdf